# How to access property of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I know I must be missing something very basic here, but I could do with a pair of fresh eyes.

I have an array of objects (see code).

I'm trying to read the values of property `variants` of each object.

I've tried many combinations. For one, if I do `object.variants` or `object[0].variants`, the result is `undefined`.

Can anybody tell me why please?

Update: I need to loop through the objects in the array and check, for each of them, the `variants` property. If it's not `null` then grab its values and log them.

```
   [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 233.84,
            "y": 82.13
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 461.27,
            "y": 79.74
        },
        "text": "xvxvs xsvx vx",
        "variants": [
            "xvxvs",
            "xsvx",
            "vx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 515.39,
            "y": 120.84
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 803.67,
            "y": 111.31
        },
        "text": "casdc adcasdcasc",
        "variants": [
            "casdc",
            "adcasdcasc"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the values of the objects? Put them into another array? – have a look at Array.prototype.map. Just get the property of the first object? – Let's say, your array is called `arr`, then it would be `arr[0].variants`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` function like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br1o396b/)

```
objects.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   console.log(element.variants); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Well assuming that you have a javascript variable with this contents:

```
var obj = 
    [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "complete": true,
            "startPoint": {
                "x": 233.84,
                "y": 82.13
            },
            "endPoint": {
                "x": 461.27,
                "y": 79.74
            },
            "text": "xvxvs xsvx vx",
            "variants": [
                "xvxvs",
                "xsvx",
                "vx"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "complete": true,
            "startPoint": {
                "x": 515.39,
                "y": 120.84
            },
            "endPoint": {
                "x": 803.67,
                "y": 111.31
            },
            "text": "casdc adcasdcasc",
            "variants": [
                "casdc",
                "adcasdcasc"
            ]
        }
    ];
```

then you can access the variants contents like this:

```
alert(obj[0].variants);
```

and here's a working demo of it: http://jsfiddle.net/66o8h5de/

So basically `obj` is an array and `obj[0]` represents the first element of this array and `obj[0].variants` is the `variants` property of the first element of this array. Of course depending on your needs you might want to loop over the elements of this `obj` array in which case you could use a `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var element = obj[i];
    alert(element.variants);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed not having variable name. I've update my question with what I want to achieve, so perhaps your answer can be more  specific (obviously my fault for not making the question clear in the first place).

Comment: Well, once you have a variable name pointing to this javascript object array you can loop through its contents using the `for` loop as shown in my answer and then accessing each individual element of this array: `var element = obj[i];`

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects where each object includes keys for more arrays. A method that uses `forEach` to iterate over your objects and then again for your variant arrays:

```js
var array = [{"type":"text","complete":true,"startPoint":{"x":233.84,"y":82.13},"endPoint":{"x":461.27,"y":79.74},"text":"xvxvs xsvx vx","variants":["xvxvs","xsvx","vx"]},{"type":"text","complete":true,"startPoint":{"x":515.39,"y":120.84},"endPoint":{"x":803.67,"y":111.31},"text":"casdc adcasdcasc","variants":["casdc","adcasdcasc"]}]

array.forEach(function(element) {
  variantArray = element.variants;
  variantArray.forEach(function(variant) {
    document.write(variant + "<br>");  
  });
  document.write("<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =  [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 233.84,
            "y": 82.13
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 461.27,
            "y": 79.74
        },
        "text": "xvxvs xsvx vx",
        "variants": [
            "xvxvs",
            "xsvx",
            "vx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 515.39,
            "y": 120.84
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 803.67,
            "y": 111.31
        },
        "text": "casdc adcasdcasc",
        "variants": [
            "casdc",
            "adcasdcasc"
        ]
    }
];


var len = arr.length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
  var obj = arr[i];
  console.log(obj["variants"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you assign it to a variable

```js
var arr =    [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 233.84,
            "y": 82.13
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 461.27,
            "y": 79.74
        },
        "text": "xvxvs xsvx vx",
        "variants": [
            "xvxvs",
            "xsvx",
            "vx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 515.39,
            "y": 120.84
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 803.67,
            "y": 111.31
        },
        "text": "casdc adcasdcasc",
        "variants": [
            "casdc",
            "adcasdcasc"
        ]
    }
]
console.log(arr[0].variants)
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more :-)

```js
var data =   
  [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 233.84,
            "y": 82.13
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 461.27,
            "y": 79.74
        },
        "text": "xvxvs xsvx vx",
        "variants": [
            "xvxvs",
            "xsvx",
            "vx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "complete": true,
        "startPoint": {
            "x": 515.39,
            "y": 120.84
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": 803.67,
            "y": 111.31
        },
        "text": "casdc adcasdcasc",
        "variants": [
            "casdc",
            "adcasdcasc"
        ]
    }
]
;

for ( var i in data ) {
  $('pre').append( data[i].variants + "\n");
}
And one more ;-)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```